# How to get the item related information in PowerShell

Tags: 2010, powershell

I have document library which contains multiple **content Types**.

Is it possible to get the documents or documents all metadata field value using PowerShell Script?

Is it possible to identify which column belongs to which content type using a PowerShell Script?

Please suggest some PowerShell scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using below script you can get the documents metadata fields value . you can store it on your local machine. create text file with name MetaDataDieldValues to save metadata fields

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$webUrl = "http://site"
$library = "DocumentsLibrary" 
$s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)    
$w = $s.OpenWeb()         
$l = $w.Lists[$library]  

Write-Host "Connecting To Site: " $webUrl  

//Create variable array $myArray to save metadata field values 
$myArray = @()
//iterate through Document Library
foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
{
  $currentItemID=$listItem.ID 

   Write-Host "    Current Item ID: " $currentItemID -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

 //Add metadata field value in myarray array seprated by @ symbol

 $myArray += $listItem.Title +"@"+$listItem["Training_x0020_Date"]+"@"+$listItem["Status"]
 Write-Host ""
 Write-Host "Current Item Values seprated By commas: " $myArray  -ForegroundColor Cyan     

}

//Finally add metadata field values in text  file 

$myArray| Out-File "C:\MetaDataDieldValues.txt" -width 120

Write-Host ""
 Write-Host   "Script execution done !"  -BackgroundColor Green
```

[SharePoint 2010 | Powershell | Download all files in document library to Network Share (File share)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varun_malhotra/2012/02/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-download-all-files-in-document-library-to-network-share-file-share/)

```
$destination = "C:\\tools\\Folder"
$webUrl = "<Url of the specific site>"
$listUrl = "<Url of the specific list. This url is complete Url and NOT relative url>"

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)

function ProcessFolder {
param($folderUrl)
$folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
    #Ensure destination directory
    $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
    {
        $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
    }
    #Download file
    $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
    $writer.write($binary)
    $writer.Close()
    }
 }

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)

 #Download files in folders

  foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
 ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
                                   }
```